# Having difficulty installing nginx using CloudFormation Helper Scripts in a yaml file

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I have installed nginx previously by writing in the commands in the UserData section, but trying to do it with cfn-init and cfn-hup is proving to be extremely difficult. The yaml file is able to successfully execute and create my instance and I can SSH into it, but the web server is not installing and showing the index.html file that I (supposedly) created. My question is focused on my Resources section mostly as this is where the install is supposed to happen. Finding yaml information on this online proves difficult so hopefully someone can guide me in the right direction. My current code is below.

```
---
Description: Create an Amazon Linux server running nginx web server
 
Parameters:
    KeyName:
        Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
        Description: Name of an existing EC2 keypair to enable SSH access to the instance
    SSHCIDR:
        Type: String
        Description: The CIDR block restricting SSH
        MinLength: 10
        Default: 131.247.0.0/16
        AllowedPattern: '(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/(\d{1,2})'
        ConstraintDescription: must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x
    
Mappings:
    Region2AMI:
        us-east-1:
            AMI: ami-00514a528eadbc95b
        us-east-2: 
            AMI: ami-04fcd96153cb57194
        us-west-1:
            AMI: ami-023e0c35fc414e78b
        us-west-2:
            AMI: ami-0528a5175983e7f28
            
Resources:
    EC2Instance:
        Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
        Metadata:
            AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
                configSets:
                    InstallAndConfig:
                        - Install
                        - Configure
                Install:
                    packages:
                        yum:
                            nginx: []
                    files:
                       /usr/share/nginx/index.html:
                        content: !
                            "<title>My name</title><h1>My name</h1>"
                        mode: '000644'
                        owner: root
                        group: root
                        
                        /etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf:
                            content: !Sub |
                                [main]
                                stack=${AWS::StackId}
                                region=${AWS::Region}
                                interval=1
                        mode: '000400'
                        owner: root
                        group: root
                        
                        /etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf:
                            content: !Sub |
                                [cfn-auto-reloader-hook]
                                triggers=post.update
                                path=Resources.Amazon Linux w/ nginx included.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init
                                action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource Amazon Linux w/ nginx included --region ${AWS::Region} --configsets InstallAndConfig
                                runas=root
                        mode: '00400'
                        owner: root
                        group: root
                    
                    services:
                        sysvinit:
                            nginx:
                                enabled: 'true'
                                ensureRunning: 'true'
                                files:
                                    - "/usr/share/nginx/index.html"
                                sources:
                                    - "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
                            cfn-hup:
                                enabled: 'true'
                                ensureRunning: 'true'
                                files:
                                    - /etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf
                                    - /etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf
        
        Properties:
            ImageId: !FindInMap [Region2AMI, !Ref 'AWS::Region', 'AMI']
            InstanceType: t2.micro
            SecurityGroups: 
            - !Ref WebserverSecurityGroup
            Tags:
            - Key: Name
              Value: Amazon Linux w/ nginx included
            KeyName: !Ref KeyName  
            UserData:
                'Fn::Base64': |
                    #!/bin/bash -x
                    yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
                    /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource Amazon Linux w/ nginx included --region ${AWS::Region} 
                    
                   
    WebserverSecurityGroup:
        Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
        Properties:
            GroupDescription: Allows HTTP
            SecurityGroupIngress:
            - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
              FromPort: 80
              ToPort: 80
              IpProtocol: tcp
            - CidrIp: !Ref SSHCIDR
              FromPort: 22
              ToPort: 22
              IpProtocol: tcp
              
Outputs:
    WebURL:
        Description: URL for web page
        Value: !Sub 'http://${EC2Instance.PublicIp}'
```

Comment: have you tried marcin solution. let us know if you. still facing the issue

Answer (score 0):

There could be many things wrong here, but one that is immediately apparent is:

```
--resource Amazon Linux w/ nginx included
```

The above, used in few places, is incorrect and should be:

```
--resource EC2Instance
```

What is more, you are missing a [CreationPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-creationpolicy.html) for your instance if you want to use `/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init`.